Casl - How to allow access to related entities?
I am building a nestjs app with CASL as a access control library. But I ran into a problem which I can't find an easy solution to: If a user has a read access to an entity, he should also have access to read other entities that are related(with key-foreign keys) to it. I am using typeorm and all entities are correctly mapped to each other.
I am expecting something like this:
can(Action.Manage, EntityX, { someField: true });
can(Action.Manage, EntityY, { entityxId :  EntityX.id });

but it seems that CASL doesn't support it.

Is related entity available through deep path on entity which you check permissions on? Casl works good in context of aggregates. You need to make available all the data for permission checks from root entity
